# Passing an element of an array (struct) through pthread_create

Tags: c, arrays, struct, pthreads

I have some issue with passing an element of an array through pthread_create as paramenter.

I have this struct:

```
struct threadInfo {
   int threadNumber;
   int sleepTime;
};
```

I initialize the array (in a function) like this:

```
struct threadInfo info[1];
```

Then in a while-loop I do this:

```
int i = 0;
...
while (i < 2) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&countMutex);
        if (threadsCount < MAX_THREAD) {
                info[i].threadNumber = ++threadsCount;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&countMutex);
                info[i].sleepTime = rand() % (10 + 1 - 1) + 1; 
                pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, lawine, &info[i]);
                i++;
        }
        else {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&countMutex);
                break;
        }
    }
```

threadsCount is a global var.

In the first turn it works fine(info[0]). But In the second round (info[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOdkA.png)) the values are wrong. [the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOdkA.png)

Can you help me?

Comment: Please don't post output as links, and don't post pictures of text but post the text.

Comment: How do you *initialize the array (in a function) like this: `struct threadInfo info[];`*?

Comment: When encountering a bug, it is always helpful to cut away the non-essential from your code until you have a ["Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example"](http://sscce.org/) so that you can (a) see and understand for yourself more clearly what went wrong (b) be able to share with others a program that they can easily save as a file, compile,  and try for themselves when trying to help you.

Comment: This is why we shouldn't use "magic numbers" in source code.

Comment: very helpful misters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going out of bounds on your array as you've only declared it to hold one element, but you're expecting it to hold 2. The number inside the square brackets in this line of code...

```
struct threadInfo info[1];
```

... isn't the highest index you can access. It's the number of elements, so if you want to have 2 elements (and thus be able to access `info[1]`) you need to allocate it like so:

```
struct threadInfo info[2];
```